# Javascript/jQuery Serialize all options in select tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, serialization

I have select box like this

```
<select size="20" multiple="" id="left_lps" name="lps[]"> 
    <option lpprobability="10" lpname="1 - Chrome" id="opt8" value="8">1 - Chrome</option>
    <option lpprobability="20" lpname="2 - Chrome" id="opt9" value="9">2 - Chrome</option>
    <option lpprobability="33" lpname="3 - Chrome" id="opt10" value="10">3 - Chrome</option>
    <option lpprobability="15.33" lpname="4 - Chrome" id="opt11" value="11">4 - Chrome</option>
    <option lpprobability="50" lpname="5 - Skype" id="opt12" value="12">5 - Skype</option>
    <option lpprobability="23" lpname="6 - Skype" id="opt13" value="13">6 - Skype</option>
    <option lpprobability="80" lpname="7 - Skype" id="opt14" value="14">7 - Skype</option>
    <option lpprobability="11" lpname="8 - Skype" id="opt15" value="15">8 - Skype</option>
    <option lpprobability="26" lpname="9 - Skype" id="opt16" value="16">9 - Skype</option>
    <option lpprobability="33" lpname="10 - Skype" id="opt17" value="17">10 - Skype</option>
</select>
```

When I serialize this I get only selected options, but I need all options in this select box. How do I do that? Also from this select box I need array of pairs (id, lpprobability).

At the end I need to get something like this:

```
lps[]=8&lpprobability[]=10&lps[]=9&lpprobability=20&lps[]=10&lpprobability[]=33 ...
```

How do I do that? If it is possible, if not I will find another way to get those pairs, but priority is to when serialize get all options in select box not just ones that are selected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to build the query string yourself as there is no magic function in jQuery that will allow you to do that. Here's how you'd do it:

Get a reference to the option elements:

```
var $select = $('select');
var selectName = $select.attr('name');
var $options = $select.find('option');
```

Go through the option elements and retrieve the value and lpprobability attribute pairs:

```
var optionPairs = $.map($options, function(element) {
    var $element = $(element);
    return selectName + '=' + $element.val() + '&lpprobability=' + $element.attr('lpprobability');
});
```

And finally, join them together with &:

```
var queryString = optionPairs.join('&');
```

Comment: Thanks for help, but I find another way. Since this select box was empty at the beginning options were added and removed from it, I decided to have some invisible div with inputs, so when I call serialize on whole form, I get exactly what I want :D